# How to get file content with Objective-git from some specific commit?

Tags: objective-c, git, objective-git

Im using this code to get file content of commit:

```
 GTBlob *blob = [repo lookUpObjectBySHA:@"d39a07ef51533a32da4bf0474462a71a40dc59e4" objectType:GTObjectTypeBlob error:NULL];
        NSLog(@"Blob: %@",[blob content]);
```

where SHA - some specific commit.
But I always get the latest version of this file. What Im doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, that to get file in some past states you need:

get GTTree from GTCommit,
then get GTTreeEntry from GTTree and after that 
get GTBlob as GTObject via objectWithTreeEntry:GTTreeEntry